# libuv: uv_close and thread safety

Tags: multithreading, libuv

I've seen it mentioned that "`uv_close` is not thread safe". I'm experienced with writing multi-threaded C/C++ code, but I'm still not sure what is being said here.

- Does this mean that `uv_close` must always be called in the main thread?
- Or, is this simply warning that `uv_close` must not be called in parallel to other uses of the handle (seems obvious..)?

I'm dealing with an `uv_async_t` handle, if that's relevant...

Comment: Where have you seen that statement? Based on [docs](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/handle.html?highlight=uv_close#c.uv_close) it _requests_ the handle to close which sounds to be safe. There are scenarios where you initialize `uv_async_t` and call `uv_async_send` on worker thread while `uv_close` it in the async callback on libuv thread

Comment: A bit of searching yields, for example, https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/709 ... Here my question seems to be answered: It may *not* be called outside of the loop thread.

Comment: All right, nice findings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the discussion here:

https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/709

`uv_close` may *not* be called outside of the loop thread. In addition, it should be mentioned that *no* `libuv` functions, aside from `uv_async_send`, are safe to call outside of the loop thread.